# When Connecting WSO2 apim in docker to mysql in local machine getting error while using useSSL=true in url

Tags: mysql, docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When Connecting WSO2 apim in docker to mysql in local machine getting error while using ssl=true in url .

Datasource connection code in apim:

```
<datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/carbon_db?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=true</url>
                    <username>userame</username>
                    <password>password</password>
                    <driverClassName>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

It works fine when useSSL=false. useSSL= true gives the following connection failure error:

```
 wso2am_1     | [2019-05-06 07:37:25,095] ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction.
    wso2am_1     | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Mysql server is 8.0 and ssl variables are as:
[image]

Comment: What is your mysql version? Is your mysql server configured to work with SSL properly?

Comment: mysql version is 8.0, yes tried SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%'; have_ssl and pem files with that. Will add that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `requireSSL=true`.